# pandas get the value of the margin/row/name/index from a single row slice of a df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is an easy answer if I could find the correct word to search on. If I make a df

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['x']=[1,2,3,4,5]
df['y']=[3,4,3,4,3]

df = df.set_index('y')
```

I take a slice

```
test = df.iloc[-1]
```

I print it:

```
print(test)

x    5
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

I want to get the 'Name', in this example corresponds to 3 but I can't find the keyword to get it?

I've tried:

```
test.index
test.index.values
test.values
test.index[0]
```

I note that with a normal df i can access any index 'n' with

```
df.index[n]
```

But once I have taken a single row slice this method no longer works? When I print 'test' there is a 'Name' value but I can't seem to access it?

please note 'test' is passed through other functions in my code so i don't really want to extract the index/Name value as a separate variable, it should be stored within 'test'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`Series.name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) attribute:

```
print (test.name)
3
```

Comment: ahhh! Lower case 'name'. I'd spent ages trying things with upper case 'Name' because when you print test it shows 'Name' as the feature I want instead of 'name'! Absolutely kicking myself! Thankyou so much!